# How to evaluate$ \int_{\partial D} \int_{\partial D} \frac{1}{|x-y|}dxdy$, where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are spheres in 3D?

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, laplacian, potential-theory

In my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376442/how-to-evaluate-int-partial-d-int-partial-d-frac1x-ydxdy-where) I asked about evaluating the following integral over the surface of a sphere in 3D:
$$
\int_{\partial D} \int_{\partial D} \frac{1}{|x-y|}dxdy,
$$
and it turned out that the answer is $(4\pi)^2$ for a unit sphere.

Now what about the case where $x$ and $y$ are not on the surface of the same sphere, but are actually on the surfaces of different spheres (both of the same radius)? That is, the integral
$$
\int_{\partial D_2} \int_{\partial D_1} \frac{1}{|x-y|}dxdy,
$$
where $x$ is on the surface of $D_1$ and $y$ is on the surface of $D_2$. Unfortunately we don't have the same level of symmetry in this situation so I am uncertain if an analytic solution is possible? Can this be solved explicitly or will numerical integration be required?

Comment: Actually there is still some symmetry from what I can see, as the integration over each sphere is essentially symmetrical with the integration that is then performed over the other one..so maybe this is explicitly solvable?

Comment: What geometry you have in mind (are the two sphere intersecting or not)?

Comment: Hint: for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\int_{\partial B(y_0,r)} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy = \frac{4\pi r^2}{\max(|x-y_0|,r)}$. i.e the potential generate by a spherical shell is constant inside the sphere.

Comment: @Fabian No the spheres are not intersecting.

Comment: @achillehui Ok, I calculated the integral to be $\frac{(4\pi r^2)^2}{|x_0-y_0|}$. Is that correct? By the way, do you know of a good book or lecture notes that deals with integrals with these?

Comment: Yes, the integral is $\frac{(4\pi r^2)^2}{|x_0-y_0|}$. For integrals of similar form, there isn't anything really interesting. However, for this particular integral in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a lot of result is known because its applications in electrostatics. You can consult any textbook on electrodynamics (e.g "Classical Electrodynamics" by J.D Jackson) for other integrals that involves the factor $\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @achillehui Ok great, I'll have a look at that book, I've heard it mentioned before. One final thing, in the case where the spheres are not separated (my previous question), that is $D_1 = D_2$, the answer is $4\pi$ in the case of a unit sphere. In the case of a non-unit sphere however, is this the correct result: $$\int_{\partial D}\int_{\partial D}{1\over |x-y|}\>dx\>dy=(4\pi)^2 r^3?$$

Comment: Yes, that is the correct result.